# Django generate pdf from a template with xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, xhtml2pdf

I try to generate a pdf file from an html template in my django app.

First i install library:

```
pip install --pre xhtml2pdf
```

then i create in my project folder an utiils.py file with this function:

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

i create my html template and then in my views.py file i create the class:

```
from yourproject.utils import render_to_pdf #created in step 4

class GeneratePdf(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
            'today': datetime.date.today(), 
            'amount': 39.99,
            'customer_name': 'Cooper Mann',
            'order_id': 1233434,
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

at this point in my urls.py i add the url for start pdf creation

```
from idocuments.views import GeneratePdf
...

url(r'^fatt_doc/(?P<fat_num>\w+)/$', GeneratePdf),
```

but when i start my app and open the link i get an error:

> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I think the problem is in my urls.py but someone can help me to know how i can call the function for generate pdf from an url?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: [mcve] and full matching traceback please.

Answer (score 1):

Use as_view() after the class name.

```
url(r'^fatt_doc/(?P<fat_num>\w+)/$', GeneratePdf.as_view()),
```